# How can I check the browser version

Tags: c#, browser

How I can check the browser version in C#? For example: `(Version 54.0.2840.71 m)` for google chrome.

Comment: what you mean Browser Version? Browsers that installed on computer or browser that browses your webpage?

Comment: asp.net application?

Comment: Please don't. Learn from the past's mistakes. Try to use feature detection rather than "knowing" what a particular browser is/isn't capable of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Request.Browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.browser(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Request.UserAgent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent.aspx)

You can get it by using Request.Browser

`Request.Browser` gives browser information with extra information regarding the browser capabilities.

User Agent gives browser information, But it gives you a raw string about the browser.

Comment: Thanks vivek nuna